# Decimal separator issue on WooCommerce custom template price.php

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, price

I have few questions regarding woo `price.php`
first I like to change the way `get_price_html()` showing the price and I couldn't find a way and then I decide to change `price.php` file and add the following lines before `get_price_html`:

```
<div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_price_class', 'price' ) ); ?>" style="color: #212529; font-weight: 700; font-size: 1.61rem; line-height: 2rem; text-transform: none; margin-top: -0.25rem;"><?php
           echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
        echo $product->get_regular_price(); ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <span class="text-danger">VAT included </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_price_class', 'price' ) ); ?>" style="color: #212529; font-weight: 700; font-size: 1.61rem; line-height: 2rem; text-transform: none; margin-top: -0.25rem;"><?php 
           echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
            echo $product->get_sale_price();
        ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <span class="text-danger">Price per KG </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

It works for me and showing the product's price in the style that I am looking for. but there is few questions:

1. As you see in `get_price_html` the price appears with `,` but in  `get_regular_price` the price shown with `.` as a decimal
2. Also when `get_sale_price` is available, it doesn't add `<strike>` to the regular price.

Totally is the arny way to edit `get_price_html` instead of `get_sale_price` and `get_sale_price`

Comment: Sorry, I mean `<strike>` . question updated.

Comment: I have updated my answer code to handle the striked regular price…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following revisited code that will solve the decimal separator issue, using WooCommerce `wc_price()` dedicated price formatting function *(that also handle the currency symbol display)*.

It will handle the striked regular price too.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_price_class', 'price' ) ); ?>" style="color: #212529; font-weight: 700; font-size: 1.61rem; line-height: 2rem; text-transform: none; margin-top: -0.25rem;"><del><?php
           echo wc_price(wc_get_price_to_display($product, array('price' => $product->get_regular_price())));
        ?></del></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <span class="text-danger"><?php _e("VAT included"); ?> </span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_price_class', 'price' ) ); ?>" style="color: #212529; font-weight: 700; font-size: 1.61rem; line-height: 2rem; text-transform: none; margin-top: -0.25rem;"><ins><?php
           echo wc_price(wc_get_price_to_display($product, array('price' => $product->get_sale_price())));
        ?></ins></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <span class="text-danger"><?php _e("Price per KG"); ?></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

It should better work.

Comment: Thanks Loic, you save me.

Comment: @M.SallarRabiei Happy that I have been able to save you :)